# Cómo deshabilitar una opcion de un select en jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo una funcionalidad con un select que tiene tres valores para desplegar A, B y C. Cuando se selecciona el primero A, se almacena dicho valor en BD.

Luego, cuando se vuelve a cargar la información grabada, se debe deshabilitar la opción A del select y dejar B y C para el despliegue en el select anterior. Esto lo hago de la siguiente forma:

```
$('#tipo option:first-child').attr('disabled',true);
```

Con lo cual el select aparece con el valor B seleccionado por default y estando el valor C también disponible para seleccionar, pero el valor A está deshabilitado.

Ahora, el usuario puede seleccionar el valor B del select y grabar. Luego al cargar los datos grabados, el select debe aparecer también con el valor B deshabilitado y seleccionado por default el valor C. Lo que no logro hacer es deshabiltar el segundo valor del select, el B.  He intentado lo siguiente, pero no funciona:

```
$("#tipo option[value='2']").prop("disabled",true);
```

Si alguien me puede ayudar, estaré muy agradecido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta esto:

$('#tipo option:eq(1)').attr('disabled',true);

Selecciona el segundo item (B) del selector y lo deshabilita.